# Want to change NLS_DATE_FORMAT in oracle DB for a particular Schema only

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

I want to change NLS_DATE_FORMAT and NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT to like below format

```
NLS_DATE_FORMAT='YYYY-MM-DD'
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT='YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3"Z"'
```

I don't want to use this in session level like `ALTER SESSION SET..` 
I cannot set this DB level.

I want this to be set in Schema level.

Comment: What do you mean with schema level? Say I log in as a user, and then query different tables from different schemas; what do you expect?

Comment: If you are just trying to avoid having to type those `alter` statements every time you log in, maybe you really want to set this in your client? Which client(s) you use will determine how to do that. IDE-type clients (SQL Developer etc.) have preferences you can set. SQL\*Plus has login files you can run automatically. Etc.

Comment: @AlexPoole Actually I'm inserting data from ETL tool. Now I'm using `alter session` statements before load and then inserting. But it's not working many times.

Comment: @Aleksej I login as user( ex. `AAA` ), the user is the owner of the schema(ex.  `AAA` ). I'll not look into any other schema. I want to set NLS formats for that (AAA)  schema alone. It can be a permanent change to the schema.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working many times"?

Comment: It's not possible. The command is "ALTER **SESSION** ..." - not "ALTER USER ..."

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Sometimes I'm  able to insert date values in the specified string format ( `NLS_DATE_FORMAT='YYYY-MM-DD'` ) and sometimes I'm getting error like string literals does not match. DB is expecting date values in default format (may be like `MM/DD/YYY`) other than what I'm altering.

Comment: Your inserts should not really be relying on NLS setting or implicit conversion anyway - can your ETL extract provide `to_date()` and `to_timestamp()` calls with the appropriate format masks, or as date/timestamp literals? The tool/client you are using to perform the inserts could still possibly set those NLS settings by default if not. It depends exactly how your process works, of course.

Comment: @AlexPoole Actually I'm doing bulk insert. Data will be handled as string here. I cannot use conversions like to_date(). I need NLS_FORMATS to be set as per my data for that schema alone

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit `ALTER SESSION` is I used earlier. But I need something else

Comment: Why do you cannot use `TO_DATE()`? Why do you need something else?

Comment: It's a dynamic bulk load. All column data will go as string. I cannot specify `to_date()`  function for a particular column, since I will not know which column contains date values. If I put `TO_DATE(Column_Name)` data will go like `"to_date('2019-08-08)"` , data will get inserted as `to_date('2019-08-08)` if I specify the column type as string. i I specify the column type as date, it will throw error.

Comment: If it's dynamic you can maybe look up the data type for the column you're inserting into, and then do `to_date('2019-08-08', 'YYYY-MM-DD')`. Incidentally, your settings imply that the extract has dates with no time component, so either the source data is all at midnight or the extract is effectively truncating them. Or it sends more than one format, but hopefully not.

Comment: "since I will not know which column contains date values" - how is it then possible to insert any data at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, This can be achieved using a **login or create session trigger** , If it is feasible for you.

You can create such a trigger on your schema and set NLS variables as following:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = ''''your format'''; 
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = ''''your format''';
```

Cheers!!